# CEDARs on Dub Stages

Tags: cedar, workflow

Quick question about anyone who has been around dialogue mixing on a stage for a feature:

I'm looking at purchasing a hardware CEDAR system for a new studio being built.

It only has 2 channels of processing.

On a stage, how are CEDAR systems used in terms of workflow?

Does the dialogue mixer re-record the dialogue via the CEDAR onto another track and then do the next voice the same way? (this is the way I currently work)

Or is it usually used as an overall bus on every voice and left on the whole time much like an outboard compressor or signal chain?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider the DNSOne RTAS plugin? I've used it and I know other people rave about it. It really doesn't use much system resources and is fully automatable too. And of course you can have multiple instances of it. Plus if you're whole workflow has it then you could have it from your dial edit phase to the final mix without having to re-record anything.

Ian

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I'm actually getting in the plug-in and the hardware unit to test out side by side to make the choice. It's about a 4th of the price of the hardware unit. It would be ideal to get the plug-in, but I want to make sure the plug-in sounds better than the hardware unit.

Comment: The plug-in and the hardware unit sound exactly the same...I've used them both. The advantage of the plug-in is you can get more than two channels. I've used up to 8 on an PT HD3 with no problems. The hardware interface is nice for automating, but you can also map the DNS One to faders on a control surface.

Comment: I used the DNS One last year and like Justin I mapped it onto my ProControl, just like having hardware. It's oh so quick to to automate the NR that way. Never used the hardware version sadly.

Answer (score 1):

We use ours in a dialogue chain. All of the dialogue goes through it together (not separately per track). Also, using a Cedar is sort of like mixing. You often have to ride the faders on it to get what you want, and you often do it in real-time. You can get automation support for it as well, but they never use it here.

The thing works wonders. I would recommend it to anyone who can possibly get their hands on it.

Comment: Thanks, Colin! So it's just set to a generic setting/threshold and you then ride the return if you run it hot into the CEDAR?